# Why is getValue preferred over !! when retrieving from a Map (NoSuchElementException vs NullPointerException)?

Tags: kotlin, null, nullpointerexception, hashmap, nosuchelementexception

When in Map using the !! operator, SonarQube issues warning [s6611 "Map" values should be accessed safely](https://rules.sonarsource.com/kotlin/RSPEC-6611/).  One solution from Sonar is to use getValue, which will throw a NoSuchElementException if the key is not found.

```
val a = mapOf<Int, Map<String, String>>()
a[999]!!["x"]        // NullPointerException
a.getValue(999)["x"] // NoSuchElementException: Key 999 is missing in the map.
```

What is the benefit of NoSuchElementException other than reporting the value of a key that is not found?

Comment: The exception and its message are far more useful. But according to Sonar’s flawed reasoning for why using `!!` on retrieved map values is always wrong, it follows that `getValue()` should also be considered wrong always, because it’s doing the same thing. IMO, it doesn’t make sense to “properly handle null” in a situation where null could never occur. You could be creating a bigger problem by adding a bunch of code for a situation that should never happen. Sometimes it’s preferable to assert and fail fast during testing when you’ve made a wrong assumption.

Comment: @Tenfour04 _"because it’s doing the same thing"_ - This is largely why I have a question.

Comment: I was editing my comment. I think their explanation for the inspection is wrong. Sometimes assertions are desirable. But the getValue way maybe should be preferred for the better error messaging.